# Filter items based on an IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items which has a property (ProductNames) which is an `IEnumerable<string>`.  How can I filter this list on the property so that I only get a list where the item matches all items in another `IEnumerable<string>` (FilterProductNames)?

I have tried the following but it seems to return all items that match anything (an OR style match) within the filter `IEnumerable`:

```
Items.Where(x => x.ProductNames.Intersect(FilterProductNames).Any())
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried to use Tim's answer below but it seems to give me an empty set so I tried with just one item in the `FilterProductNames` but this still just returned me nothing so I tested the same filter by doing the following:

```
if (count == 1)
{
    // this will return me 4 items
    Items = Items.Where(x => x.ProductNames.Contains(FilterProductNames.First()));
}
else
{
    // when I remove the above if, this will return me 0 items filtering on the same thing
    Items = Items.Where(x => x.ProductNames.All(pn => FilterProductNames.Contains(pn)));

    // have also tried the other version on tim's answer but to no avail:
    // Items = Items.Where(x => !x.ProductNames.Except(FilterProductNames).Any());
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Sorry for the bad wording which has caused some confusion, I am after items that contain all the names in `FilterProductNames` but are not limited to just the items in `FilterProductNames` so for example if I search for items that have product names of Test and Test1, it should bring back any item that contains both those names as well as any other name.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.All`:

```
Items.Where(x => x.ProductNames.All(pn => FilterProductNames.Contains(pn)))
```

or - possibly more efficient - using `! ... Except.Any`:

```
Items.Where(x => !x.ProductNames.Except(FilterProductNames).Any());
```

---

**Edit** acc. your comment/edit: *"...all items that contain all the names in FilterProductNames"*

Then you have to reverse the statement:

```
Items.Where(x => FilterProductNames.All(fp => x.ProductNames.Contains(fp)));
```

or

```
Items.Where(x => !FilterProductNames.Except(x.ProductNames).Any());
```

Comment: Hi I just tried both of these variants but they both return me an empty set

Comment: @Pete: i have tested it with simple sample data and it worked as expected. So there must be something special in yours. Edit your question and show a short example which show  this wrong behaviour. Otherwise we could just guess (case, spelling, white-spaces, `null`s etc.)

Comment: Hi tim, I have added examples of what works and what doesn't, let me know if you need more info

Comment: @Pete: But you haven't shown really more than before. Of course it's possible that 4 items have the **first** product in the list and none has **all**. Without more informations(sample data) i would simply say it's working as expected ;)

Comment: but if there is only one item in the filter list then shouldn't both ways return the same result set?

Comment: @Pete: No, since your first query returns all items where **at least one** product-name of the `ProductNames` sequence is in the filter-list. So if there are three product-names and one of them is the first of the filter-list it will be returned. My query returns only items where **all** of it's product-names are in the filter-list. So if this contains only one item and the `ProductNames` are more than one (or different) this will not be returned.

Comment: Ah ok I see I have worded my question wrong.  I need a result set that is like a multiple contains, so it doesn't limit the results to only have items that match the FilterProductNames exaclty but all items that contain all the names in FilterProductNames

Comment: @Pete: you just need to reverse it. Edited my answer.

Comment: Ah brilliant, that's the one.  I just can't get my head around the filtering lists with lists!  Thanks for the help